# C# validating multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox, errorprovider

I have almost 20 textboxes and to check all i have to call validate event 20 times each using errorprovider. Is there any efficient way other than that.

Comment: I think you can get an answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959018/validating-several-textboxes-on-a-c-sharp-windows-form-at-the-same-time

Comment: Thanks but i want to check validation on runtime, the link provides information about validation at the time of submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.textBox1.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.textBox_Validating);
this.textBox2.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.textBox_Validating);
this.textBox3.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.textBox_Validating);

// And so on for the 20 boxes.
private void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;

    // Do whatever yo need to do with textbox here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create validators (RequiredFieldValidator or whatnot) for each of them, then assign them all to the same ValidationGroup.  You can enforce validation of all the controls in that group at once.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

Comment: Could you be little more specific because the link redirects to asp.net and i'm working on a desktop application.

Comment: Sorry about that, I assumed web!